# Date formatting in Swift that supports iOS 13+

Tags: ios, swift, date, swiftui

I bet this is simple. I'm trying in Xcode playgrounds to play with getting a string date

```
let string = "2022-11-27 00:00:00 +0000"
```

and converting that into a Date object that's formatted like DD-MM-YYYY

```
func airdateFormat(_ key: String) -> Date? {
  let expectedFormat = Date().formatted(.dateTime.day().month(.wide).year())
  let date = try! Date(strategy: expectedFormat)
  return date 
}
```

I also tried

```
func airdateFormat(_ key: String) -> Date? {
    guard let dateString = self[key] as? String else { return nil }
    let dateFormatted = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "MM-DD-YYYY", options: Int, locale: Locale?)
    return dateFormatted().date(from: dateString)
}
```

}

I'm parsing this Date string from json hence the guard/else statement

Comment: FYI - `DD` is day of year, not day of month. Use `dd`. `YYYY` is almost aways meant to be `yyyy`. There is a very subtle difference only noticed for dates at the end of the year. Never use `YYYY` unless you have a clearly understood reason to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a format that matches your input to parse the string to a `Date`

If you want to use the `DateFormatter`

let string = "2022-11-27 12:34:56 +0000"

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
let date = formatter.date(from: string)
```

and for recent OS versions you use a `FormatStyle`

```
let formatStyle = Date.FormatStyle()
    .year(.defaultDigits)
    .month(.twoDigits)
    .day(.twoDigits)
    .hour()
    .minute()
    .second()
    .timeZone()

let date = try formatStyle.parse(string)
```

Comment: thank you Joakim. I'd like to return the Date though in "MM-dd-yyyy". When I run my code, I'm still seeing it as ""yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"

Comment: @Sam `Date` doesn't have a format. You only need to worry about a format when you need to convert between `Date` and `String` (either way). This answer correctly gives you a `Date` from the JSON string. If you later wish to show the user the date then you need to format the `Date` into a `String` using whatever format you wish.